# Matlab: dlmread is too slow

Tags: matlab, file

I have a text file like this:

```
first line - text
second line - text
third line - text
num num num num num num
....
num num num num num num
rest of text
```

I want to read one column at a time, and I use this:

```
size = 50000;
M=zeros(size,1);
for i=3:size+2
    M(i-2,1) = dlmread('filename.ext', '    ', [i 1 i 1]);
end
```

It works, but it take long long time. Why is that? It is just reading text! I do it in c++ and it take seconds using standard functions!

Comment: you should use `fread` then... that'll be fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a text file. The only possibility to find a certain row is parsing the full file until this row is reached. This is what `dlmread` internally does each time you call it.

Use `dlmread('filename.ext', '    ', [3 1 size+2 1]);` to read all at once.